# Add encoding key for rgbKey and rgbIV for security

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding

Good day experts. I am wondering what to do with regard to the two encoding keys shown below. Obviously, if these are exposed in the code, the key could be decrypted and password exposed. I was looking for ways to mitigate this risk. I need to make sure the Key and IV will match when I use this subroutine for decryption. The scheme itself ensures 1024 bit encryption. However, if the keys themselves are vulnerable, there is a chance the clear-text password these two are trying to protect could be exposed.

```
try
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptData);
            byte[] rgbKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678");
            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("87654321");
            //1024-bit encryption
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(1024);
            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, desCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] EncryptedText = new byte[(int)memoryStream.Position];
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            memoryStream.Read(EncryptedText, 0, EncryptedText.Length);
            cryptoStream.Close();
            memoryStream.Dispose();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Any passwords that are encrypted are vulnerable anyway. Don't do it. Just don't. Hash them, salt them, pepper them if you like, but don't encrypt them.

Comment: Ok, can I use the existing method calls but do a hashing/salting of them? Do you have an example or two that shows these as best practice?

Comment: 1. **Do not use DES for new work**, it is no longer considered secure and has been superceeded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) DES only has key size is only 56 bits which is not considered to be secure, AES supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits. See [Security comparison of DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181/5121).
 2. What does "1024 bit encryption" mean, DES ony had one key size: 56-bits. 3. `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptData)` is not a good solution, it is better to use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I think according to the article I got this from said the combination of both keys plus a third would encrypt to equivalent of 1024 bit. I do think the previous commenter mentioning using hash/salt is a better overall choice. Do you have an example that shows using C# Method call through class?

Comment: Note: Considering the IV as a key or part of a key is incorrect. The IV only protects the first block, for DES the first 8-bytes. The IV is not the equivalent of a key and is usually not secret. The protection resides in the key which for DES is 56-bits (in 8-bytes, only 7-bits are used per key byte).

Comment: The bigger question is what are you trying to accomplish? If a password is being encrypted, it that really necessary as opposed to just using a password verifier?

Comment: Because the password is being stored in the database. My concern is someone sniffing the equipment username and password, then being able to act as that user on our active directory. That is the root reason.

Comment: Can anyone explain how I could use this example from http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx as my hash/salt? I would be quite happy using the Sha512 for my purposes.

Comment: Ok, using the encrypt/decrypt in code is not working out. I have this password stored in the database; perhaps I can use column-level encryption in the database? But I've not dealt with this before so I need some guidance.

Comment: I decided to use Secure String class, would this be an acceptable choice or should I use column level encryption in the database, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option is to use SecureString class and use database level encryption or at least encrypt the column.